# Codechef: Longest Weird Subsequence

Tags: dynamic-programming

The question can be found at http://www.codechef.com/MARCH12/problems/LWS/

This problem can be solved using dynamic programming. The trick to this problem was to come up with a good dp state. We can make use of the fact that the only allowed characters in the input string S[1..n] are the lowercase Latin letters i.e. 'a' – 'z'. Thus, the distinct number of characters that can appear cannot be greater than 26.

Hence we come up with the following dp state: 
dp[k][c1][c2] = length of the LWS for the substring S[1..k] such that the non-decreasing subsequence ends with c1 and the non-increasing subsequence ends with c2. 
Once we have decided the state, we can easily come up with the following recurrence: 
To calculate dp[k][c1][c2] we try to add the lowercase letter S[k] to either non-increasing subsequence or non-decreasing subsequence or we do not add it to any of them.

Thus, if c1<=S[k]: dp[k][S[k]][c2] = max(dp[k][S[k]][c2], dp[k-1][c1][c2]+1) and similarly if c2>=S[k] dp[k][c1][S[k]] = max(dp[k][c1][S[k]], dp[k-1][c1][c2]+1) The final answer can be found out by iterating over c1 and c2 and finding the maximum value out of all dp[n][c1][c2]. 
We can see that we have to calculate 26 * 26 states for every possible length of a substring from 1 to n where n is the length of the string. Thus, the order of the solution is O(26*26*n).

However, am in a fix when we need to solve it for when the elements in the list are numbers between 0 and 10^6

Comment: Please investigate paragraphs.

Comment: Please break up your question into paragraphs, as it's very difficult to read right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a tradeoff between time and space. The solution given in the question will not work when the elements of the sequence are numbers between 0 and 10^6.

We know that longest Increasing Subsequence can be found in O(nLgn). 
Let the original sequence be saved in array A
Let there be an array I, such that I[n] will save the length of longest increasing subsequence till A[n]. 
Let there be an array D, such that D[n] will save the length of longest decreasing subsequence from A[n] to end of A.
Now, you need to find max(I[k] + D[k]) - 1.